# multi level login does not go to the assigned menu

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make multi level user login menu, but it doesn't go the assigned menu according to different user level. what did i do wrong?`

```html
 # LOGIN CEK TO USER TABLE LOGIN
  $loginSql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$txtUser' AND password='".md5($txtPassword)."'";
  $loginQry = mysql_query($loginSql, $koneksidb) or die ("Query Salah : ".mysql_error());

  # IF SUCCEED
  if (mysql_num_rows($loginQry) >=1) 
  {
   $loginData = mysql_fetch_array($loginQry);
   $_SESSION['SES_LOGIN']  = $loginData['kode_user']; 
   $_SESSION['SES_ADMIN']  = $txtUser;
   $_SESSION['level']      = $loginData['level'];
   // Refresh
   if($row['level'] == "admin")
        {
            
            header("Location: admin.php");
        }
        else if($row['level'] =="academic")
        {
            header("Location: academic.php");
        }
        else if($row['level'] == "student")
        {
            
            header("Location: student.php");
        }
   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?open'>";
  }
```

`

Comment: 1) md5 is old should not be used anymore http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php.. 2) Your wide open for SQL injection attacks.. 3) mysql_* are deprecated you should use mysqli_* functions or PDO instead... 4)  after a header() function you should use exit(), die() or __halt_compiler() to stop the script's execution

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: You never set `$row` you set `$loginData`

Answer (score 0):

You never set `$row` you set `$loginData` therefore

```
if($row['level'] == "admin")...
else if($row['level'] =="academic")...
else if($row['level'] =="student")...
```

will not work. You should use this test:

```
if($loginData['level'] == "admin")...
else if($loginData['level'] =="academic")...
else if($loginData['level'] =="student")...
```

OR use the session variable (making sure `session_start()` is at the top of the script):

```
if($_SESSION['level'] == "admin")...
else if($_SESSION['level'] =="academic")...
else if($_SESSION['level'] =="student")...
```

### Warning!

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.